# cheap backup mic's, rode nt5 or oktavas mk012?

Tags: backups, microphone, cheap

hello all,

thinking about buying some backup mics, for more dangerous situations, and other experiments...i have two options either matched pair of rodes nt5, or oktavas mk012...i'm a little bit on aktava side, because oktava set has 6 capsules, but i need better sounding mics, and i never used any of these :)

thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various topics discussing the Rode NT5 on gearslutz:

http://www.gearslutz.com/board/high-end/21089-rode-nt5-condensor-mics.html
http://www.gearslutz.com/board/low-end-theory/717420-at4041-mk012-rode-nt5-overheads-guitar.html
http://www.gearslutz.com/board/high-end/16018-rode-nt5.html

The discussion going on in these topics should be taken with a grain of salt because you don't know how biased or knowledgeable someone might be, but there are a few example recordings (some even comparing it to the oktavas) buried amidst the brand-bashing and -praising.

As always, the best thing you can do is to try them out :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Line Audio CM3 mics. They are incredible.
[link text](http://www.lineaudio.se/linemic.htm)

Comment: Wow, that's £91. Do you have any recordings made with these online?

Comment: Hi. Yeah check out the first recordings I did with them at http://snd.sc/GTmuvk
They were in a rycote in ORTF configuration and recorded on a SD744t.

Comment: Thanks, they're nice recordings. Love the trolleybus cable sounds btw. In London we now have hydrogen powered buses which I've been meaning to record... they sound pretty futuristic. (Although I just watched this: http://createdigitalmusic.com/2012/04/designing-the-sound-of-a-real-car-an-audi-from-silence-to-noise/)

Comment: found some recordings on soundcloud, sounds good, and available in europe...will research more about these :)

Comment: For the money these mics are incredible, hand built in Sweden. I'd get a pair before they raise in price, which i'm sure they will once people realise how good they are.
I'm using them for ambience recording for a feature film over next couple of days in Latvia. Will post some more sounds soon.

Comment: I'm really interested in these, for stereo recordings. Which rycotte is required ? They have the same size of other pencil mics ?

Comment: did some more research on these mics, found a lot of samples on gearslutz, and actually i'm going for these, they are out of stock at the moment but will be available on april 20 again...so will grab them, thanks for sudgestion SC Audio ;) 

Comment: Sweet. Do you have a picture of these mics mounted in the Rycote?

Comment: I have just put up a blog post about putting these mics in the Rycote: 
http://scaudio.co/2012/05/line-audio-cm3-mics-in-rycote-s-series/

Answer (score 1):

A matched pair of the Oktava MK-012 is a good buy. These mics sound far better than the price tag would suggest. They are a little on the "dark" side, but well worth owning a pair of these. I have recorded outside sfx with these......fireworks, crowds etc, as well as music in the studio on guitars and other instruments. 
Michael Joly at oktavamod.com apparently does mods on them that makes them sound even better, though I haven't tried his modded mics myself. There seems to be plenty of good feedback around regarding the mics he has done.